# Show "No invocations performed" error when write "Verify" test method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, xunit

We have a service that is being used inside another service:

```
namespace ConsoleCalculator.Services
{
    public interface ICalculatorService
    {
        int GetLineCount(string inputLineCount);
    }
}

namespace ConsoleCalculator.Services
{
    public class CalculatorService : ICalculatorService
    {
        private readonly ICalculatorValidationService _calculatorValidationService;

        public CalculatorService(ICalculatorValidationService calculatorValidationService)
        {
            _calculatorValidationService = calculatorValidationService;
        }

        public int GetLineCount(string inputLineCount)
        {
            _calculatorValidationService.ValidateLineCount(inputLineCount);
            return Convert.ToInt32(inputLineCount);
        }
    }
}
```

Now we need to write a test for the desired service:

```
namespace ConsoleCalculator.Test.Services
{
    public class CalculatorServiceTest
    {
        private Mock<ICalculatorService> _calculatorService = new Mock<ICalculatorService>();
        private Mock<ICalculatorValidationService> _valculatorValidationService = new Mock<ICalculatorValidationService>();
        public CalculatorServiceTest()
        {
            _valculatorValidationService
              .Setup(q => q.ValidateLineCount(It.IsRegex("[^0-9]")))
              .Throws(new Exception());

            _calculatorService
                .Setup(q => q.GetLineCount(It.IsRegex("[^0-9]")))
                .Throws(new Exception());
        }


        [Fact]
        public void When_Input_Not_A_Number_Should_Return_Exception()
        {
            Assert.Throws<Exception>(() => _calculatorService.Object.GetLineCount("123a"));
        }

        [Fact]
        public void When_Call_Method_Should_Call_Exactaly_One_ValidateLineCount_Method()
        {
            _calculatorService.Object.GetLineCount(It.IsAny<string>());
            _valculatorValidationService.Verify(x => x.ValidateLineCount(It.IsAny<string>()), Times.Once);
        }
    }
}
```

The purpose of writing the second test was to make sure that my test service is called once. But when running the test, I see the following error:

> Moq.MockException :  Expected invocation on the mock once, but was 0
> times: x => x.ValidateLineCount(It.IsAny())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the moq you have given, the validation service method will not be invoked as an exception is thrown on calling `GetLineCount` and hence the test fails.

Instead of setting this moq

```
_calculatorService
                .Setup(q => q.GetLineCount(It.IsRegex("[^0-9]")))
                .Throws(new Exception());
```

Try like this

```
[Fact]
public void When_Call_Method_Should_Call_Exactaly_One_ValidateLineCount_Method()
{
         
var calSrvc = new CalculatorService(_valculatorValidationService.Object);
 
calSrvc.Object.GetLineCount(It.IsAny<string>());
   
_valculatorValidationService.Verify(x => x.ValidateLineCount(It.IsAny<string>()), Times.Once);
}
```

Comment: Let's assume that there is a datebase operation inside the desired method. when we use instance of service instead of Moq object the database operation is not really called?

As you know, this is a test method, I don't want my database operations to be performed every time it is executed

Comment: But everything passed to the service method is a moq (like the validation cal service here). Lets say we have a DB operation and a repository/context object is used. We pass in the moq implementation for the repo/context to the service and an actual call wont be fired